# how to fix Warning: preg_match()

Tags: php

I have the below scripts and they give me this warning.

```
( ! ) Warning: preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Unknown modifier ']'
```

This is my code:

```
if ((preg_match("<[^>]*script*\"?[^>]*>", $check_url)) || (preg_match("<[^>]*object*\"?[^>]*>", $check_url)) ||
    (preg_match("<[^>]*iframe*\"?[^>]*>", $check_url)) || (preg_match("<[^>]*applet*\"?[^>]*>", $check_url)) ||
    (preg_match("<[^>]*meta*\"?[^>]*>", $check_url)) || (preg_match("<[^>]*style*\"?[^>]*>", $check_url)) ||
    (preg_match("<[^>]*form*\"?[^>]*>", $check_url)) || (preg_match("\([^>]*\"?[^)]*\)", $check_url)) ||
    (preg_match("\"", $check_url))) {
die ();
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: check the syntacx\x of pregmatch

Comment: Delimiters! You need to add them

Comment: There's also a lot of repetition - think about how you could simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern must be changed like this

```
preg_match("/<[^>]*script*\"?[^>]*>/", $check_url);
```